# printf in newlib is not working in baremetal ARM environment

Tags: c, gcc, arm, bare-metal, newlib

I am working in a bare-metal ARM project in which I am trying to integrate newlib library. As a beginner, I am trying to make the `printf` function working first so that I can see the standard output through UART. I have already gone through many on-line documents that describes how to get this done. Instead of blindly following the steps, I did everything myself by learning things from those documents. I made many mistakes in the beginning but fixed them one by one and kept the work progressing.
       But now I have stuck with an issue which no one has ever seems to be experienced so far, according to my internet search. Now let me come to the actual, issue.

The `printf` function is returning without calling my implementation of `_write` function. When I debug I can see that the `printf` is invoking other system calls that I have written myself(Like `_isatty`, `_sbrk` and `_fstat`).

These are the system calls that I have implemented in order to resolve the linking issues(undefined references)

```
extern char __heap_start__;
extern char __heap_end__;

void _exit(int status)
{
    while (1);
}
void *_sbrk(int incr)
{
    static char *heap_end = &__heap_start__;
    char *base = heap_end;
    if(heap_end + incr > &__heap_end__)
    {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return (void *)-1;
    }
    heap_end += incr;
    return base;
}
int _write(int fd, char *buff, int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        UART0_write_char(buff[i]);
    }
    return i;
}
int _read(int fd, char *buff, int size)
{
    return 0;
}

int _open(const char *name, int flags,int mode)
{
    return 0;
}

void _close(int fd)
{
}
int _isatty(int fd)
{
    return 1;
}
int _fstat(int fd, struct stat *st)
{
    st->st_mode = S_IFCHR;
    return 0;
}
off_t _lseek(int fd, off_t offset, int whence)
{
    return 0;
}
```

My linker script

```
STACK_HEAP_BOUNDARY_OFFSET = 0;
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 512K
    SRAM  (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x40000000, LENGTH = 32K
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        startup.o (.text)
        *(.text .txt.*)
        *(.glue_7)
        *(.glue_7t)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } > FLASH

    .ARM.extab :
    {
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
    } > FLASH

    .ARM :
    {
        *(.ARM.exidx*)
    } >FLASH

    .rodata :
    {
        *(.rodata .rodata.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } > FLASH

    .data :
    {
        __data_load__ = LOADADDR (.data);
        __data_start__ = .;
        *(.data .data.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __data_end__ = .;
    } > SRAM AT > FLASH

    .bss :
    {
        __bss_start__ = .;
        *(.bss .bss.*)
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __bss_end__ = .;
    } > SRAM

    .heap :
    {
        __heap_start__ = .;
        PROVIDE(end = __heap_start__);
        PROVIDE(_heap_start = __heap_start__);
        . = . + ((LENGTH(SRAM) - (. - (ORIGIN(SRAM)))) / 2);
        . += STACK_HEAP_BOUNDARY_OFFSET;
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __heap_end__ = .;
        PROVIDE(_heap_end = __heap_end__);
    } > SRAM

    .stack :
    {
        __stack_start__ = .;
        . = . + (LENGTH(SRAM) - (. - (ORIGIN(SRAM))));
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __stack_end__ = .;
        __stack_size__ = __stack_end__ - __stack_start__;
        __IRQ_stack_top__ = (__stack_start__ + (__stack_size__ / 2));
    } > SRAM
}
```

My Makefile

```
TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX:=arm-none-eabi-
CC := $(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)gcc
LD := $(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)ld
AS := $(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)as
AR := $(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)ar -cr
OBJCOPY := $(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)objcopy

RM := rm -f

TARGET := image.hex

OBJS := startup.o $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))

CFLAGS := -mcpu=arm7tdmi-s -g3 -Wall -I. -gdwarf-2
AS_FLAGS := -mcpu=arm7tdmi-s -g3 -gdwarf-2

LD_FLAGS := -Wl,-Map,$(TARGET:%.hex=%).map -nostartfiles

LD_SCRIPT := lpc2138.ld

all :   $(TARGET)

$(TARGET) : $(TARGET:%.hex=%.elf)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $< $@

$(TARGET:%.hex=%.elf) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ -T $(LD_SCRIPT) $(OBJS) $(LD_FLAGS)

startup.o : startup.s
    $(AS) $(AS_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean :
    $(RM) $(TARGET) $(TARGET:%.hex=%.elf) $(TARGET:%.hex=%).map *.o
```

Please let me know if any further information is needed from my side. Thank you in advance

EDIT:

Start-up code

```
/* Standard definitions of Mode bits and Interrupt (I & F) flags in PSRs */
Mode_USR    =   0x10
Mode_FIQ    =   0x11
Mode_IRQ    =   0x12
Mode_SVC    =   0x13
Mode_ABT    =   0x17
Mode_UND    =   0x1B
Mode_SYS    =   0x1F

I_Bit       =   0x80    /* when I bit is set, IRQ is disabled */
F_Bit       =   0x40    /* when F bit is set, FIQ is disabled */

    .text
    .arm
    .global _start
    .func   _start
_start:
    B   _reset              /* Reset vector */
    B   _loop               /* Undefined Instruction */
    B   _loop               /* Software Interrupt */
    B   _loop               /* Prefetch Abort */
    B   _loop               /* Data Abort */
    NOP                     /* Reserved */
    LDR pc, [pc, #-0x0FF0]  /* VicVectAddr */
    /* LDR pc, _fiq_addr */
    B   _loop               /* FIQ Handler */
_reset:
/* Enable FIQ and IRQ */
    MSR CPSR_c,#(Mode_IRQ | I_Bit | F_Bit)
    LDR SP, =__IRQ_stack_top__
    MSR CPSR_c,#Mode_SVC

/* Relocate the .data section (copy from ROM to RAM) */
    LDR r0,=__data_load__
    LDR r1,=__data_start__
    LDR r2,=__data_end__
_l1:
    CMP r1,r2
    LDMLTIA r0!,{r3}
    STMLTIA r1!,{r3}
    BLT _l1

    /* Clear the .bss section (zero init) */
    LDR r1,=__bss_start__
    LDR r2,=__bss_end__
    MOV r3,#0
_l2:
    CMP r1,r2
    STMLTIA r1!,{r3}
    BLT _l2

    LDR sp,=__stack_end__
    LDR FP,=__stack_end__
    LDR r0,=main
    MOV lr,pc
    BX  r0
_loop:
    B   _loop

/* _fiq_addr:
    .word VIC_FIQ_handler
*/
    .endfunc
    .end
```

Comment: first and foremost, give up on printf, if you are using this strictly to get printf it is a massive waste.  make a simple binary/octal/hex printer, takes like 10 lines of code...

Comment: to get this to work I start by stripping every function in the backend and make them pass.  before it can call printf you are correct it is going to do an istty if not other functions perhaps an fopen.  just let those all return the pass value.  then it will get to write...

Comment: As a sidenote: `printf` & friends are most likely not a good idea for a bare-metal embedded system. They are too bloated, even more as they are based on the stream-io functions. Additionally many coding guides forbit variable argument lists. Better write specific conversion/output routines for your output link, if you really need them at all.

Comment: it looks like you have done that.  shouldnt need _sbrk for a printf, so you are doing something else in your program (_sbrk is tied to malloc basically)

Comment: @old_timer all other function are being called so far are returning pass values.

Comment: flash and sram are separate, have you confirmed that .data is being copied over and/or your format string is a const (.text or .rodata) and not in .data?

Comment: there are also 50-100 line printfs you can just use for baremetal that dont have any C library calls or minimal at least, dont support float of course, but are lighter on the overhead.  I prefer just to print hex numbers out with my 20 line function and that is more than adequate (if a blinking led is not enough).

Comment: @old_timer my .date is definitely being copied over. I can show my start-up code. The format string I tried is a simple string contant(Just "Hello world") which as per y knowledge should go to the .rodata

Comment: you can just look to see where it went, I use objdump -D but you could maybe use readelf.

Comment: do you call `fflush(stdout)` after `printf()`?

Comment: or put a newline at the end of the format?

Comment: Did you try compiling with the nosys spec? I.e. Passing `-specs=nosys.specs` to the linker. Otherwise it may link to the default implementation of _write().

Comment: @ensc That really helped. It's working now. Thank you!